# Find Atmel Studio 6 installer?

Tags: atmel-studio

I know nothing about Atmel Studio other than roughly what it is, and have never used it.

One of the production techs just came to me saying that a shortcut he's clicked for years to program a Atmel doesn't work anymore.  This shortcut runs Atmel Studio 6.  It starts up, displays its splash screen, then after a few seconds barfs on something like "Can't create window".  I figure some software component of Studio or something it relies on got accidentally wiped out on that machine.

I'd like to re-install Studio 6, hoping that the deleted component gets re-installed in the process.  However, I can't find any Studio 6 install file on any reputable site.  I checked the Microchip and Atmel sites, including the "software archive" section of the Microchip site.  The only version of Studio I could find anywhere is 7.

Various web sites out there claim to have Studio 6 installers, but most of them are of questionable heritage.  Element 14 (who I'd trust) claims to have it, but the page is not available when you click on it.  It looks like DigiKey used to have it too, but that it's been taken down.  It almost seems like Microchip has gone out of their way to make Studio 6 unavailable, but that's not been their policy with old versions of MPLAB.

So the question is, **Where do I find Atmel Studio 6 installer** on a official or highly reputable site?

I can install Studio 7, but I'm worried about some minor incompatibility, plus then someone has to actually know something about Studio to set it up, figure out how to point it to the file to program, etc.  Nobody here, including me, knows anything about Studio, and I'd rather avoid spending the time to delve into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an official archive of old versions of Atmel Studio on the Microchip website [here](http://www.microchip.com/mplab/avr-support/avr-and-sam-downloads-archive).

The download links for Atmel Studio 6.0 and 6.2 both appear to still work.

In fact they have versions all the way back to 4.13 still available.

Comment: Excellent! That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I don't know why that didn't turn up in searches on the Atmel site, but now I know it's there.

Comment: @OlinLathrop not sure. I just googled Atmel Studio 6 and it was the second result.

Comment: Hmm.  I might have searched in Bing, but I definitely searched on the Atmel site directly.

Comment: Problem solved.  I re-installed that same version of Studio 6 that was on the machine in production, and things are working again.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @downvoter - care to explain what exactly is wrong with the answer?

Comment: Clearly there is nothing wrong with your answer.  It was correct, helpful, and I used it to solve my problem.  I already upvoted and accepted it, so unfortunately there is nothing further I can do.

Answer (score 2):

List of versions (incl. direct links to Atmel Website):
https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/Atmel_Studio

It should be possible to open AS6 projects with AS7 as well (it will convert the project settings file upon first opening it)

Comment: "www.microcontroller.net" doesn't give me confidence.

Comment: @OlinLathrop microcontroller.net is a German electronic enthusiast website which provides usually a good information source. Of course not being run by a company makes it as reputable as other forums.

Comment: @OlinLathrop even if the site isn't recognized as the moderately famous one it is, the key point is that the links it provides **appear to be links to files on Atmel servers**.  It is indeed possible to play tricks on a user where a link appears to go somewhere other than where it does, but if one is careful about the actual link being downloaded, then something found on Atmel's servers would be either something placed there by them or by someone who broke into their servers.

Comment: One more addition: It also lists the most current (1417) version of AS7; The Atmel site doesn't do that (yet, 1417 is available in the Microchip website)